# Can non-nullable strings be nullable?

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

I've read a few articles now that explain how great nullable reference types are when enabled in C# 8 and it seems majority of the work is done with the compiler and how the compiler tries to help you from setting non-nullable strings to null.

Given some simple method and added validation below

```
public static string DoSomethingWithFileName(string filename)
{
       ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(filename);
       if(filename == string.Empty) 
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(filename));
}
```

Should we still check for null even though the filename is a non-nullable type?

And if so, how would the filename become null if nullable reference types are enabled?

Comment: See duplicate: it's just a warning, and unless you can be sure _all_ your _and_ all _calling_ code is compiled with nullable enabled, and they're correctly applied everywhere (say, a database column or something from a file), and there's no reflection being used whatsoever, then you can be sure. Still it doesn't hurt to have those checks there.

Comment: Thanks @CodeCaster didn't see that duplicate at first when searching

Answer (score 0):

You can make a variable or property nullable by appending a `?` after the type. Like `string? filemame` in your case.

And remember that unlike Dart's null safety, it's just a handy compiler lint at the moment. Therefore you still can have null value in the runtime for a non nullable variable. So yeah! You still need to check for null depending on use case.